# O que significa o (-X,-H,-d) deste comando (curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d) e como fazê-lo pelo arquivo php?

Tags: php, post, libcurl

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d
```

Preciso efetuar esse comando e enviar um JSON para determinada API que retornará uma resposta mas não sei como a estrutura disso ficaria em um arquivo PHP e o que significam esses dados (-X -H -d). Já vi parecido com isso quando fazemos o comando com o `cmd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d
```

Segundo a documentação:

- [`-X`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-X): Especifica o método de solicitação (`GET`, `HEAD`, `POST` ou `PUT`) para usar ao se comunicar com o servidor.
- [`-H`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H): Indica que um *Header* extra será incluso na requisição.
- [`-d`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d): Envia os dados especificados em uma solicitação `POST` para o servidor.

Em PHP seria algo parecido com isto:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$url = "URL";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$resultado = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

print_r($resultado);
```

Se você pretende enviar mais dados nessa requisição, é necessário usar a função `json_encode()` para codificá-los adequadamente. Veja um exemplo:

```
$foo = "foo";
$bar = "bar";

$dadosJson = json_encode(array( "foo"=> $foo, "bar" => $bar));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dadosJson);
```

Comment: @Josiel Funcionou?

Comment: @Josiel Poste o código no www.pastebin.com  e coloque o link aqui!

Comment: desculpa a demora estou aprendendo a usar o site ainda. Foi a primeira pergunta que fiz e não sei como funciona direito... Deu certo sim ... obrigado pela ajuda... mas estou tendo problemas quanto ao json_encode. Quando uso um array dentro de outro ele transforma os dois arrays  em um json, quando na verdade o de dentro deveria permanecer como um array contendo json dentro...

Comment: @Josiel Sem problemas, aproveite e faça um **tour** (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo site. Quanto ao `json_encode` é aconselhável fazer outra pergunta sobre isso!

Comment: @Josiel E assim que possível marque está resposta como "aceita" clicando na seta abaixo da pontuação da resposta!

Comment: Ok ... vou fazer sim pra aprender como usar a ferramente corretamente... qt ao json encode vou fazer outra pergunta sim... obrigado.